# Questions about a natural map $\mathcal{G} \to f_*f^{-1}\mathcal{G}$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $\mathcal{F}, \mathcal{G}$ be sheaves on topological spaces $X, Y$ respectively and $f: X \to Y$ a continuous map. By definition, for an open set $U \subseteq Y$,
$$ 
f_*f^{-1}\mathcal{G}(U) = \lim_{\rightarrow}_{V \supseteq f(f^{-1}(U))} \mathcal{G}(V).   \qquad (1)
$$
Since $U \supseteq f(f^{-1}(U))$, $U$ is one of $V$'s on the right hand side of (1). If $\mathcal{G}(V)$ is a subset of $\lim_{\rightarrow}_{V \supseteq f(f^{-1}(U))} \mathcal{G}(V)$, then the map 
$$g: \mathcal{G}(U) \to \lim_{\rightarrow}_{V \supseteq f(f^{-1}(U))} \mathcal{G}(V)$$ 
can be taken as the inclusion map. But now we take direct limit. Could we still take $g$ as the inclusion map? Thank you very much.

Edit: What is the natural map $\mathcal{G} \to f_*f^{-1}\mathcal{G}$ explicitly?

Comment: A minor comment: you don't use $\mathcal F$ anywhere in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general $g$ won't be an inclusion. For example, suppose there is an open set $U \subset Y$ that is not in the image of $f$. Then $f(f^{-1}(U)) = \emptyset$ and $f_*f^{-1}\mathcal G(U) = 0$.

In fact, this happens for any inclusion of open subset $i: U \to Y$. In this case, what the natural transformation does is to restrict the sheaf $\mathcal G$ from $Y$ to $U$ in the sense that ${\mathcal G}_{|U} (V) = \mathcal G (U \cap V)$

On the other hand, as long as $f$ is surjective, you should get your inclusion. More generally, it is enough to require that the image of $f$ be dense in $Y$.